# Postfix Calculator Java

Tags: java, calculator, postfix-notation, stack

Ok so I have to read in a postfix expression from a file. The postfix expression must have spaces to separate each operator or operand. What I have so far works only if there is no spaces between the operators or operands in the input file. (i.e. if the file has 12+ the result I get is 3.) In order to do this I think that I need to tokenize the input, but I am not sure how. This is what I have so far. Thank you for any responses.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class PostfixCalc{
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
File file = new File("in.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
String input = sc.next();
Stack<Integer> calc = new Stack<Integer>();
while(sc.hasNext()){
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int r = 0;
    if(Character.isDigit(c)){
       int t = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        calc.push(t);
    }
    else if(c == '+'){
        x = calc.pop();
        y = calc.pop();
        r = x+y;
        calc.push(r);
    }
     else if(c == '-'){
        x = calc.pop();
        y = calc.pop();
        r = x-y;
        calc.push(r);
    }
     else if(c == '*'){
        x = calc.pop();
        y = calc.pop();
        r = x*y;
        calc.push(r);
    }
     else if(c == '/'){
        x = calc.pop();
        y = calc.pop();
        r = x/y;
        calc.push(r);
    }
}
 }
 int a = calc.pop();
System.out.println(a);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Take a look at [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). It tokenizes on white-space (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) by default.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you need to change, which you can do step by step.

1. Declare your `Stack` to contain `Integer`s rather than `Character`s.
2. In the code that reads the input, rely on `String`s instead of `Character`s.
3. Parse operands using `Integer.parseInt()`. This will convert `String`s to `Integer`s. (Actually, it converts them to `int`s, but in your case this difference doesn't matter.)
4. Set the scanner delimiter using `Scanner.useDelimiter()` to `\s+`, this will match a sequence of any whitespace characters.

There are of course countless of other ways to process your input but I tried to give you an idea of how to change your existing code to do what it needs to do.

Answer (score 3):

In order to tokenize you can use the `String.split()` with a single space as a **separator**;

```
String[] inputs = input.split(" ");
```

Here is a full solution that I've just written that which uses a **Stack** implementation based on a **singly linked list** in order to make a postfix calculator;

#### A - PostFixCalculator

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PostFixCalculator {

    private static final String ADD = "+"; 
    private static final String SUB = "-";
    private static final String MUL = "*";
    private static final String DIV = "/";

    public void calculateFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            String input = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(input + " = " + calculate(input));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    private int calculate(String input) {
        SinglyLinkedListStack<Integer> stack = new SinglyLinkedListStack<>();

        String[] inputs = input.split(" ");

        return handleCalculation(stack, inputs);
    }

    private static int handleCalculation(SinglyLinkedListStack<Integer> stack, String[] el) {
        int operand1, operand2;

        for(int i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            if( el[i].equals(ADD) || el[i].equals(SUB) || el[i].equals(MUL) || el[i].equals(DIV) ) {
                operand2 = stack.pop();
                operand1 = stack.pop();
                switch(el[i]) {
                    case ADD: {
                        int local = operand1 + operand2;
                        stack.push(local);
                        break;
                    }

                    case SUB: {
                        int local = operand1 - operand2;
                        stack.push(local);
                        break;
                    }

                    case MUL: {
                        int local = operand1 * operand2;
                        stack.push(local);
                        break;
                    }

                    case DIV: {
                        int local = operand1 / operand2;
                        stack.push(local);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                stack.push(Integer.parseInt(el[i]));
            }
        }

        return stack.pop();
    }

}
```

#### B - SinglyLinkedListStack

```
public class SinglyLinkedListStack<T> {

    private int size;
    private Node<T> head;

    public SinglyLinkedListStack() {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void push(T element) {
        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node(element);
        } else {
            Node<T> newNode = new Node(element);
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }

        size++;
    }

    public T pop() {
        if(head == null)
            return null;
        else {
            T topData = head.data;

            head = head.next;
            size--;

            return topData;
        }
    }

    public T top() {
        if(head != null)
            return head.data;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    private class Node<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> next;

        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }

}
```

#### C - Demo

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class PostFixCalculatorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PostFixCalculator calc = new PostFixCalculator();
        calc.calculateFile("postfix.txt");
    }
}
```

#### D - Sample Input File: "postfix.txt"

```
6 5 2 3 + 8 * + 3 + *
```

#### E - Demo Output

```
6 5 2 3 + 8 * + 3 + *  = 288
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a scanner

simply use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read file, then use it's method readLine to get the line

Then use

```
String tokens[] = line.split("\\s+?")
```

and you will get the array of "tokens", which can be processed within your code.

to identify the number, you may use the following regex:

```
Pattern isNumber = Pattern.compile("^\\d+?$")
if (isNumber.matcher(token).matches()) {
    push(Integer.parseInt(token));
}
```

Comment: Using a scanner is actually easier here. `next()` by default would retrieve the next whitespace-separated token. Patterns can be used afterwards, of course.